# How to load dynamic images in custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

How to load dynamic images in custom `ListView`  iI follow this tutorial to show ListView in horizontal  http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34  but the problem is this example used same sample icon,but I want to use dynamic images which I get from resource or web parsing

**HorizontalListViewDemo.java :**

```
public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Activity {  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

        setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);  

        HorizontialListView listview = (HorizontialListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);  
        listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);  
    }  

    private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",  
        "Text #2",  
        "Text #3" };   

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {  

        @Override  
        public int getCount() {  
            return dataObjects.length;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public Object getItem(int position) {  
            return null;  
        }

        @Override  
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
            View retval =  
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);  
            TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);  
            title.setText(dataObjects[position]);  

            return retval;
        }

    };

}
```

**Layout file :**

```
   <linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res 
   /android" android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff">  

    <com.devsmart.android.ui.horizontiallistview android:id="@+id/listview"      
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:background="#ddd">  

        </com.devsmart.android.ui.horizontiallistview>
          </linearlayout> 

       <linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com 
      /apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical"      
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#fff">  

    <imageview android:id="@+id/image" 
     android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:scaletype="centerCrop" 
    android:src="@drawable/icon">  

    <textview android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textcolor="#000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  

    </textview></imageview></linearlayout>
```

**HorizontalListView.java**

```
 public class HorizontalListView extends  
               AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
protected int mCurrentX;
protected int mNextX;
private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
protected Scroller mScroller;
private GestureDetector mGesture;
private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClicked;
private boolean mDataChanged = false;


public HorizontalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

private synchronized void initView() {
    mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    mRightViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentX = 0;
    mNextX = 0;
    mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
}

@Override
public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener 

        listener)  {
    mOnItemSelected = listener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
    mOnItemClicked = listener;
}

@Override
public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener 
      listener) {
    mOnItemLongClicked = listener;
}

private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mDataChanged = true;
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInvalidated() {
        reset();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

};

@Override
public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}

@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    //TODO: implement
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    }
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    reset();
}

private synchronized void reset(){
    initView();
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    //TODO: implement
}

private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), 
        MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
}



@Override
protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int 
    right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    if(mAdapter == null){
        return;
    }

    if(mDataChanged){
        int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mNextX = oldCurrentX;
        mDataChanged = false;
    }

    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
        int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
        mNextX = scrollx;
    }

    if(mNextX <= 0){
        mNextX = 0;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }
    if(mNextX >= mMaxX) {
        mNextX = mMaxX;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    }

    int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

    removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
    fillList(dx);
    positionItems(dx);

    mCurrentX = mNextX;

    if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
        post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestLayout();
            }
        });

    }
}

private void fillList(final int dx) {
    int edge = 0;
    View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getRight();
    }
    fillListRight(edge, dx);

    edge = 0;
    child = getChildAt(0);
    if(child != null) {
        edge = child.getLeft();
    }
    fillListLeft(edge, dx);


}

 private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
    while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < 
         mAdapter.getCount()) {

        View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, 
            mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
        rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

        if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
            mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
        }

        if (mMaxX < 0) {
            mMaxX = 0;
        }
        mRightViewIndex++;
    }

}

 private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
    while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
        View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, 
             mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
        leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mLeftViewIndex--;
        mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
}

private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
    View child = getChildAt(0);
    while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
        mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mLeftViewIndex++;
        child = getChildAt(0);

    }

    child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
        mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
        removeViewInLayout(child);
        mRightViewIndex--;
        child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    }
}

private void positionItems(final int dx) {
    if(getChildCount() > 0){
        mDisplayOffset += dx;
        int left = mDisplayOffset;
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, 
         child.getMeasuredHeight());
            left += childWidth + child.getPaddingRight();
        }
    }
}

public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return handled;
}

protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
    synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
        mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    }
    requestLayout();

    return true;
}

protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    return true;
}

private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new 
         GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, 
           velocityY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
            float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
            mNextX += (int)distanceX;
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                if(mOnItemClicked != null){

      mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 +  
        i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                if(mOnItemSelected != null){

     mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 
    1  + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (isEventWithinView(e, child)) {
                if (mOnItemLongClicked != null) {

  mOnItemLongClicked.onItemLongClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 
    1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    private boolean isEventWithinView(MotionEvent e, View child) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        int[] childPosition = new int[2];
        child.getLocationOnScreen(childPosition);
        int left = childPosition[0];
        int right = left + child.getWidth();
        int top = childPosition[1];
        int bottom = top + child.getHeight();
        viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        return viewRect.contains((int) e.getRawX(), (int) e.getRawY());
    }
};

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting image in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the link below. Someone already have written a library for it.

[Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

I used [this](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) library in my recent projects and it worked flawlessly.

Hope it will help.

Comment: i did but problem is iage will not shown only text will be show

Comment: Text will be loaded normally but these libs will allow your app to lazy load the dynamic images. These libraries will help your app to stay interactive, which is a good thing from user experience point of view.

Comment: HorizontialListView   not support  imageview

Comment: i did but the problem is if i replace with HorizontialListView   is display image   if i write again HorizontialListView  is not show image

Answer (score 0):

Here are those what you are looking for..

- [Android-lazy-image-loader-example.html](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-lazy-image-loader-example.html)
- [Loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/)

Comment: if i simply replace HorizontalListView  with Listview image will be show

Answer (score 0):

As @Varundroid said you can make use of Android universal image loader, which works awesomely good. But that is a huge library for such a small purpose. You may consider writing your own [Asynchronous Image Loader for Android ListView](http://javatechig.com/android/asynchronous-image-loader-in-android-listview/)

You can change the following in your adapter class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();            
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        NewsItem newsItem = (NewsItem) listData.get(position); 
        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
        } 
        return convertView;
    }
```

**For Downloading image in separate thread**

```
class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference imageViewReference;

    public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.list_placeholder));
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The above link has the complete tutorial for your purpose.

Comment: Lol that lib is not HUGE. It is just 127KB which is nothing.

Comment: @Varundroid. Agreed. You may even consider the lib lenience too. (If you use Universal Image Loader code in your application you should inform the author about it ( email: nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com ) like this:)

Comment: And your code is not caching the images where libs i mentioned also caching the image for a specific period of time, which will decrease the network interaction and will load the images quickly from cache next time when user will open the app. Remember the real motive of lazy loading is not only keep app interactive, but makes image loading fast as well.

Comment: @Varundroid. Caching needs a extra effort, which is not mentioned in the question above. Also, I too have used this lib, which is damn cool to use with the features like caching using week reference, file cache, etc. I don't contradict your statement saying don't use. But considering lenience and requirements for a async list, I would consider writing my own rather using this lib.

Comment: Man what are you saying. No you don't need to send an email till the time you modify the code. It's an apache 2.0 license. So don't worry you don't need to inform anyone that you have used their lib. If every single person who is using Universal Image loader lib has to send and email to Author the author must have gone crazy with emails as there are 100000 of developers who used this lib. :)

Comment: Yeah the guy who asked the question did not mention cacheing but i believe its good to show everyone a right way of doing things and cache the dynamic images is indeed a right way to go.

And if something is already done, why rewrite it. It will decrease your productivity mate.

Comment: @Varundroid. Cool agreed!