# HorizontalListview not scrolling

Tags: android

my horizontallistview not scroll help me please i get solution of my previous post [How to load dynamic images in custom ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715818/how-to-load-dynamic-images-in-custom-listview)   this HorizontalListView class will display image  but problem is  is not scrolling if i add 3 images only 1 &half display  how do i add scrol view in this code help me please. every thing  is work fine only Horizontal Listview not scroll

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.Scroller;


public class HorizontalListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

  public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
  protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
  private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
  private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
  protected int mCurrentX;
  protected int mNextX;
  private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
  protected Scroller mScroller;
  private GestureDetector mGesture;
  private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
  private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
  private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
  private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClicked;
  private boolean mDataChanged = false;
  private boolean mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly = true;


  public HorizontalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
  }

  private synchronized void initView() {
    mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    mRightViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentX = 0;
    mNextX = 0;
    mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
  }

  @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
      mOnItemSelected = listener;
    }

  @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
      mOnItemClicked = listener;
    }

  @Override
    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
      mOnItemLongClicked = listener;
    }

  private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
      public void onChanged() {
        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
          mDataChanged = true;
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
      }

    @Override
      public void onInvalidated() {
        reset();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
      }

  };

  @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
      return mAdapter;
    }

  @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
      //TODO: implement
      return null;
    }

  @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
      if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
      }
      mAdapter = adapter;
      mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
      reset();
    }

  /**
   * @param visibleOnly - If set to true, then height is calculated
   * only using visible views. If set to false then height is
   * calculated using _all_ views in adapter. Default is true.
   * Be very careful when passing false, as this may result in
   * significant performance hit for larger number of views.
   */
  public void setHeightMeasureMode(boolean visibleOnly) {
    if(mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly != visibleOnly) {
      mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly = visibleOnly;
      requestLayout();
    }
  }

  private synchronized void reset(){
    initView();
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
  }

  @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
      //TODO: implement
    }

  private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
      params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
  }

  @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

      if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        int height = 0;

        if(mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly) {
          int childCount = getChildCount();
          for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            v.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            if(v.getMeasuredHeight() > height) {
              height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
          }
        } else {

          /* Traverses _all_ views! Bypasses view recycler! */

          HashMap<Integer, View> mRecycler = new HashMap<Integer, View>();
          int childCount = getAdapter().getCount();
          for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            int type = getAdapter().getItemViewType(i);
            View convertView = mRecycler.get(type);
            View v = getAdapter().getView(i, convertView, this);
            mRecycler.put(type, v);

            v.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            if(v.getMeasuredHeight() > height) {
              height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
          }
        }

        if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
          int maxHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
          if(maxHeight < height) {
            height = maxHeight;
          }
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), height);
      }
    }

  @Override
    protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top,
        int right, int bottom) {
      super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

      if(mAdapter == null){
        return;
      }

      if(mDataChanged){
        int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mNextX = oldCurrentX;
        mDataChanged = false;
      }

      if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
        int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
        mNextX = scrollx;
      }

      if(mNextX <= 0){
        mNextX = 0;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
      }
      if(mNextX >= mMaxX) {
        mNextX = mMaxX;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
      }

      int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

      removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
      fillList(dx);
      positionItems(dx);

      mCurrentX = mNextX;

      if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
        post(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
            requestLayout();
            }
            });

      }
    }

  private void fillList(final int dx) {
    int edge = 0;
    View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    if(child != null) {
      edge = child.getRight();
    }
    fillListRight(edge, dx);

    edge = 0;
    child = getChildAt(0);
    if(child != null) {
      edge = child.getLeft();
    }
    fillListLeft(edge, dx);


  }

  private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
    while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

      View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
      addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
      rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

      if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
        mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
      }

      if (mMaxX < 0) {
        mMaxX = 0;
      }
      mRightViewIndex++;
    }

  }

  private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
    while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
      View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), this);
      addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
      leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
      mLeftViewIndex--;
      mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
  }

  private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
    View child = getChildAt(0);
    while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
      mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
      mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
      removeViewInLayout(child);
      mLeftViewIndex++;
      child = getChildAt(0);

    }

    child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
      mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
      removeViewInLayout(child);
      mRightViewIndex--;
      child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    }
  }

  private void positionItems(final int dx) {
    if(getChildCount() > 0){
      mDisplayOffset += dx;
      int left = mDisplayOffset;
      for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
        left += childWidth;
      }
    }
  }

  public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
    requestLayout();
  }

  @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
      handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
      return handled;
    }

  protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
      float velocityY) {
    synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
      mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    }
    requestLayout();

    return true;
  }

  protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    return true;
  }

  private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
      public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onDown(e);
      }

    @Override
      public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
          float velocityY) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
      }

    @Override
      public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
          float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
          mNextX += (int)distanceX;
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
      }

    @Override
      public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
          View child = getChildAt(i);
          int left = child.getLeft();
          int right = child.getRight();
          int top = child.getTop();
          int bottom = child.getBottom();
          viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
          if(viewRect.contains((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY())){
            if(mOnItemClicked != null){
              mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
            }
            if(mOnItemSelected != null){
              mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
            }
            break;
          }

        }
        return true;
      }

    @Override
      public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
          View child = getChildAt(i);
          int left = child.getLeft();
          int right = child.getRight();
          int top = child.getTop();
          int bottom = child.getBottom();
          viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
          if (viewRect.contains((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY())) {
            if (mOnItemLongClicked != null) {
              mOnItemLongClicked.onItemLongClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
            }
            break;
          }

        }
      }

  };



}
















               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff"
android:src="@drawable/icon"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>



    </LinearLayout>












              <com.schoollunchapp.HorizontalListView
           android:id="@+id/listview"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="0.6"

           android:background="#EEEEEE">

 </com.schoollunchapp.HorizontalListView>
```

Comment: Paste the XML please.

Comment: xml is fine not issuw on that   wheni used previousHoriontalListview  its scrolling but not display image.  this horizontalListView  show image but not scrolling

Comment: In the above pasted XML code, the HorizontalListView is not in the scope of the top level linear layout. Is this just a copy/paste error or the actual code?

Comment: @Horschtele : I think it is, judging by this : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17721245/revisions . I guess it's just a copy/paste error, but you're right about the scope of the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: is not copy aste error is error on this HorizontalListview lcas which is not scroling helpme find bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev); //this is always true during scrolling
    return handled; //returning true will stop the listview functions to scroll it
}
```

---

```
@Override
  public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
      float distanceX, float distanceY) {

    synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
      mNextX += (int)distanceX;
    }
    requestLayout();

    return true;
  }
```

This above code is the problem

According to me the listview won't scroll if you return true in the dispatchTouchEvent function, which is always true while scrolling in your case. the onScroll gesture always returns true and the listview never scrolls.

You are trying to perform the scrolling manually.
try returning false and don't handle the scrolling manually.

I can't read your complete code because its too long, but i have spotted the problem for you, now you can handle it any way you want.

Comment: The above code is taken from the code you provided in your question.

Comment: you can find the the onScroll function and try returning false from it.
Make a new project for trial and try returning both true and false combinations from ontouchevent & onScroll gesture(4 possibilities), and log something when you are inside a function, this way you will understand in which order they are called and in which case they are functioning right.